# Perl split a string on a repeating pattern in the most efficient manner?

Tags: perl, split, design-patterns, repeat

I'd like to split a string that has a certain repeating pattern, for example:

```
$string = "GGGGG-SOMETHING-ELSE-GGG-LAST";
```

to

```
@array=(-SOMETHING-ELSE-,-LAST);
```

my attempt so far as a  perl newbie

```
split(/G{2,}/,$string);
```

Unfortunately this results in only patterns of GG being split on- not the greedy GGGGG or GGG patterns that I has hoped for resulting in 2 array elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this seems to (mostly) work as intended.  The following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_="GGGGG-SOMETHING-ELSE-GGG-LAST";
my @a=split(/G{2,}/,$_);
print join(",",@a) . "\n";
```

produces the output:

```
,-SOMETHING-ELSE-,-LAST
```

The issue is that there's a first element that's the empty string.  So, to fix that, you can do something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_="GGGGG-SOMETHING-ELSE-GGG-LAST";
my @a=grep{$_ ne ""}(split(/G{2,}/,$_));
print join(",",@a) . "\n";
```

And this produces what you want:

```
-SOMETHING-ELSE-,-LAST
```

Comment: I switched computers to an Ubuntu 11 machine, and your one-liners as well as my technique worked fine. I think this was an artifact of my version of Perl.

Comment: Simply `grep $_, split /G{2,}/` works fine. No need to do a comparison on each element as the null string is false.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code in my machine and it works fine:

```
$string = "GGGGG-SOMETHING-ELSE-GGG-LAST";
print join(':', split(/G{2,}/,$string));
```

returns:

```
:-SOMETHING-ELSE-:-LAST
```

The version of perl I'm using is: v5.10.1

Can you please add some more info about how you running it?